# Objective-C: Лучший способ для сохранение времени в плеере

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

У меня есть аудиоплеер. Нужно чтобы он запоминал время последней остановки аудио и в следующей сессии пользователь мог продолжить прослушивание с места остановки. Я делаю это с помощью `NSUserDefaults`. Нужно ли запоминать время остановки с помощью `NSUserDefaults`или есть более лучшее решение для моей задачи?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
if (_index == 0) {
    self.audioPlayer = [[AudioPlayer alloc] init];
    [self setupAudioPlayer:@"1"];
        _timeElapsed.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"time0"];
        _currentTimeSlider.value = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] floatForKey:@"time 0"];
        [self setCurrentTime:self];
}
}

- (void)setupAudioPlayer:(NSString*)fileName
{

    NSString *fileExtension = @"mp3";

    [self.audioPlayer initPlayer:fileName fileExtension:fileExtension];
    self.currentTimeSlider.maximumValue = [self.audioPlayer getAudioDuration];

    self.timeElapsed.text = @"0:00";

    self.duration.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-%@",
                          [self.audioPlayer timeFormat:[self.audioPlayer getAudioDuration]]];

    [self playAudioPressed:_playButton];
}

-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{

    [self.audioPlayer pauseAudio];
}

- (IBAction)playAudioPressed:(id)playButton
{


    [self.timer invalidate];
    if (!self.isPaused) {
        [self.playButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"]
                                   forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                                      target:self
                                                    selector:@selector(updateTime:)
                                                    userInfo:nil
                                                     repeats:YES];

        [self.audioPlayer playAudio];
        self.isPaused = TRUE;

    } else {
        [self.playButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play.png"]
                                   forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [self.audioPlayer pauseAudio];
        self.isPaused = FALSE;
    }
}

- (void)updateTime:(NSTimer *)timer {


    if (!self.scrubbing) {
        self.currentTimeSlider.value = [self.audioPlayer getCurrentAudioTime];
    }
    self.timeElapsed.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                             [self.audioPlayer timeFormat:[self.audioPlayer getCurrentAudioTime]]];

    self.duration.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-%@",
                          [self.audioPlayer timeFormat:[self.audioPlayer getAudioDuration] - [self.audioPlayer getCurrentAudioTime]]];

    if (![self.audioPlayer isPlaying]) {
        [self.playButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play.png"]
                                   forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.audioPlayer pauseAudio];
        self.isPaused = FALSE;

    }
    if (self.isPaused == TRUE) {
        if (_index == 0) {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:_duration.text forKey:@"timeImage0"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:_timeElapsed.text forKey:@"time0"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setFloat:_currentTimeSlider.value forKey:@"time 0"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        }
}
}

- (IBAction)setCurrentTime:(id)scrubber {
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(updateTime:)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:YES];

    [self.audioPlayer setCurrentAudioTime:self.currentTimeSlider.value];
    self.scrubbing = FALSE;
}
- (IBAction)userIsScrubbing:(id)sender {
    self.scrubbing = TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Нет. Более лучшего решения для вашей задачи нет.